# i keep getting this error "TypeError: g is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

so I am making an Amazon clone and for that, I am using react-router-dom version 6 so I can navigate the header with the link but whenever I use the link function it gives me this error. below is my code from the header. if some know abhout it plz let me know

```
import React from 'react';
import './Header.css';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import ShoppingBasketIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShoppingBasket';
import{ Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className='header'>
       <Link to="/">
        <img className='header_logo' src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/amazon/amazon_PNG11.png" alt="" />
        </Link>

      <div className="header_search">
        <input className='header_searchInput'  type='text' />
         <SearchIcon className="header_searchIcon"/>
          </div>

          <div className="header_nav">
            <div className="header_option">
                <span className="header_optionlineOne">
                    hello guest
                </span>
                <span className="header_optionLineTwo">
                    Sign In
                </span>
            </div>
            <div className="header_option">
            <span className="header_optionlineOne">
                    Returns
                </span>
                <span className="header_optionLineTwo">
                    & orders
                </span>
            </div>
            <div className="header_option">
            <span className="header_optionlineOne">
                   your
                </span>
                <span className="header_optionLineTwo">
                    prime
                </span>
            </div>
           <Link to="/Checkout"> <div className="header_optionBasket" >
              <ShoppingBasketIcon/>
                <span className="header_optionLineTwo  ">
                    0
                </span>
            </div></Link>
          </div>
          </div>
          



)
}

export default Header
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `react-router-dom`. It's some other function. Are you using any `useEffect` for pages you're trying to navigate using `<Link/> ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.